# How can I know if the current string is shorter or longer then this string before I have changed it by one character, in swift?

Tags: string, swift

I am inserting/deleting the characters in string. With every character, string is longer or shorter. How can I know if current string is shorter or longer then this string before I have changed it by one character? For instance:

```
mystr = "jhdjshdgfshjdgfsjhdfghgjshgf"

func textDidChange(notification: NSNotification)
{
    inputFromUser.string?.characters.count //to get current length of string
    inputFromUser.selectedRange().location //to get current position of cursor
}
```

Questions is how to get previous length of string after deleting/inserting character in mystr.

**Update**
As suggested below by Alexey Sobolevsky I have tried the willSet and didSet in the following way (see below), but I am getting not difference between old and new value (deltaLength) of string length but only the current string length. Where can be the mistake ?

```
class Comparing
{
    var deltaLength = Int()
    var lengthOfDNA: Int = 0
    {
        willSet(newlengthOfDNA)
        {
        }
        didSet
        {
            if lengthOfDNA > oldValue
            {
                deltaLength = lengthOfDNA - oldValue
            }
        }
    }
}

func textDidChange(notification: NSNotification)
{
    let objectComparing = Comparing()
    objectComparing.lengthOfDNA = (inputFromUser.string?.characters.count)!
    let deltaLength = objectComparing.deltaLength
    displayingFeature.integerValue = deltaLength
}

@IBOutlet weak var displayingFeature: NSTextField!
```

Something wrong with usage of textDidChange(notification: NSNotification) part, the code for Comparing class is working, I have tested it in playground.

**Update2**
Finally I have got the right code! The Property Observer (as it is written above) should be placed in Controller class, not in other class (as above in Comparing class).

**Update3**
One strange thing more with the implementation of The Property Observer. When I open txt file and start to insert/delete one character the deltaLength at this first step is strange number, different every time, and next deleting/inserting steps are correct. May be somebody have idea what is the reason for this? This happens only with text when it is open from file, not typed.

Comment: Unclear, show some code sample.

Comment: @kebs I have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Property Observer *didSet*. It is called just after you set a new value to a variable.

```
var mystr: String {
    didSet {
        print("This is the current value: \(mystr)")
        print("This is the old value: \(oldValue)")
        if mystr.characters.count > oldValue.characters.count {
            print("The current value length is greated than the old one")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will try, I am in learning process I have to look how to use this.

Comment: You can look it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) in Property Observers section.

Comment: I have updated the question using the Property Observer, but I am not getting the delta length, where can be my mistake?

Comment: Try to add other cases: lengthOfDNA == oldValue and lengthOfDNA < oldValue. Then it should work.

Comment: I have tried, but it didn't work, still in the displayingFeature: NSTextField! I have only the current length of the typed string and not deltaLength.

Comment: Try to stop with a debugger on the first line of didSet to check the values of lengthOfDNA and oldValue. May be it will help.

Comment: I have found the reason. The Property Observer in my case,when I am using the code with textDidChangeNotification, should be placed in Controller class, not in separate class. Thanks again for the answer. At the end it became the key for me to get the functionality I wonted !